# How to create a table based on a two-dimensional array?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, itext

```
private List<List<String>> tableOverallList;
```

i have a series of list in this list. it contains 8 values in each list. i need to place it in the table created. i would like to have 2 Rows with 8 columns. for the 1st Row i have this list.

```
String[] tableTitleList = {" Title", " (Re)set", " Obs", " Mean", " Std.Dev", " Min", " Max", "    Unit"};
List<String> tabTitleList = Arrays.asList(tableTitleList);
```

help me to place the 1st list of values inside the List `tableOverallList` in the 2nd Row. i will try managing with the rest of the list.

```
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3); // 3 columns.

        PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 5"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 6"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 7"));
        PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 8"));

        table.addCell(cell1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
        table.addCell(cell3);
        table.addCell(cell4);
        table.addCell(cell5);
        table.addCell(cell6); 
        table.addCell(cell7);
        table.addCell(cell8);

        document.add(table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really easy. So you have data in a nested list. For instance:

```
public List<List<String>> getData() {
    List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    String[] tableTitleList = {" Title", " (Re)set", " Obs", " Mean", " Std.Dev", " Min", " Max", "Unit"};
    data.add(Arrays.asList(tableTitleList));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ) {
        List<String> dataLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        i++;
        for (int j = 0; j < tableTitleList.length; j++) {
            dataLine.add(tableTitleList[j] + " " + i);
        }
        data.add(dataLine);
    }
    return data;
}
```

This will return a set of data where the first record is a title row and the following 10 rows contain mock-up data. It is assumed that this is data you have.

Now when you want to render this data in a table, you do this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
List<List<String>> dataset = getData();
for (List<String> record : dataset) {
    for (String field : record) {
        table.addCell(field);
    }
}
document.add(table);
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

You can find the full source code here: [ArrayToTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ArrayToTable) and this is the resulting PDF: [array_to_table.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/array_to_table.pdf)

If you only want 2 rows, a title row and a data row, change the following line:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ) {
```

Into this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ) {
```

I've provided a more generic solution because it's more elegant to have generic code.

Comment: thanks a lot.. sir, do u have any idea about scene builder. i linked javafx with scene builder. i have many tab's in scenebuilder. in 1 tab, i have many charts and tables. i want to save it in a form of PDF. is it possible..?

Comment: I have no experience with Java fx. I do not accept invitations to chat. My time is valuable. I try to spend it well.

Comment: ho okay.. its not about chatting. that was also a question..? any how, thanks for your valuable answer. it worked well..

Comment: Now I see, somebody else invited me to chat. i'll give him the same answer I gave you ;-)