# How can I put data in specific cells in a table on a PDF form using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

I want to create a table in a PDF and then assign values (phrases) to specific cells in that table.

I would assume it would be something like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5); // the arg is the number of columns

// Row 1
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(docTitle);
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.BorderWidth = 0;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(0, 0, cell); // <= col 0, row 0. I would expect to be able to do something like this
```

...but the only example code I've found just adds cells to the table, one after the other, without specifying which cell of the table that cell data should be associated with. Such as:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5); // the arg is the number of columns

// Row 1
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(docTitle);
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.BorderWidth = 0;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
table.AddCell(cell);

// Row 2
PdfPCell cellCaveat = new PdfPCell(subTitle);
cellCaveat.Colspan = 2;
cellCaveat.BorderWidth = 0;
table.AddCell(cellCaveat);

// Row 3
PdfPCell cellImportantNote = new PdfPCell(importantNotice);
cellImportantNote.Colspan = 5;
cellImportantNote.BorderWidth = 0;
table.AddCell(importantNotice);
```

Is there a more specific way to add cells to a table than just one at a time, hoping they are placed in the right spot?

Note: docTitle, subTitle, and importantNotice are Paragraphs that have already been created, like so:

```
var titleFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 11, BaseColor.BLACK);
var docTitle = new Paragraph("UCSC - Direct Payment Form", titleFont);
doc.Add(docTitle);
```

Comment: Imagine that you are creating an HTML table and create your `PdfPTable` likewise. Your choice of words *hoping they are placed in the right spot* is strange.

Comment: If you add content to a table in the wrong order, then you shouldn't be surprised that the contents aren't in the right spot. Your assumption that you can add cells using methods such as `table.AddCell(0, 0, cell);` is wrong. Developers have been using iText to add cells in the correct order for 15 years. Those who wanted to create an array first, used something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24404686/1622493